# Why is my sprite shaking when touching another physics body?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, physics

I have a sprite which position is manipulated by the accelerometer like this:

```
-(float)movement {
  self.accelerometerData = self.motionManager.accelerometerData;
  float xAccelerationPosition = 0;
  if ((self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x)<-0.1) {
    xAccelerationPosition = 30 * self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
  }
   if ((self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x)>0.1) {
    xAccelerationPosition = 30 * self.accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
  }


  return xAccelerationPosition;
}
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

  if ((self.player.position.x + [self.playerData movement]) < self.frame.size.width &&
      (self.player.position.x + [self.playerData movement]) > 0){

      [self.player setPosition:CGPointMake((self.player.position.x + [self.playerData movement]), self.player.position.y)];

  }

}
```

methods are in different classes.

I also have a physics body on the player and on the scene, but whenever the xAccelerationPosition gets too high the sprite starts shaking on both sides of the screen. Why?

Comment: Does it have a crush on it?  .... <.<

Comment: They might be enjoying their time a bit too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feed the player body's velocity (or apply impulse) with the accelerometer data rather than updating the player's position directly since this will bypass the physics collision handling, leaving it to resolve any penetration with other bodies in the next frame.